# Failed to receive data from socket.io

Tags: node.js, typescript, flutter, dart, socket.io

The attached code creates a room for some users who connect to a certain room.
After all users are connected, a counter starts.
Until then everything working.
On the server side, console.log is sending the counter correctly.
However, on the client side, it only receives the first emit, in this case count 50.
I am not finding the problem.

Dart

```
import 'package:date_time_flutter/model/Sala.dart';
import 'package:date_time_flutter/model/Usuario.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

class ChatFase1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final Usuario usuarioAutenticado;
  final Sala sala;

  const ChatFase1({Key? key, required this.usuarioAutenticado, required this.sala}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChatFase1> createState() => _ChatFase1State();
}

class _ChatFase1State extends State<ChatFase1> {
  List<String> messages = []; // Lista de mensagens do chat
  TextEditingController messageController = TextEditingController(); // Controlador do campo de texto
  int countdownValue = 0;
  IO.Socket? socket;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Iniciar a conexão com o servidor Socket.IO
    socket = IO.io('https://DateTimeCounter.AidanWenceslau.repl.co', <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
    });
    socket!.on('connect', (_) {
      print('Connected to server');
      socket!.emit('id_sala', {'salaId': widget.sala.id, 'maxUser': widget.sala.maxUser, 'idUsuario': widget.usuarioAutenticado.id});
    });

    // Receber atualizações do contador do servidor
    socket!.on('countdown', (data) {
      print('Countdown ok: ' + data.toString());
      setState(() {
        countdownValue = data;
      });
    });

    // Lidar com a desconexão do servidor
    socket!.on('disconnect', (_) {
      print('Disconnected from server');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Encerrar a conexão com o servidor Socket.IO ao sair da tela
    socket?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Countdown: $countdownValue'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: ListView.builder(
                reverse: true, // Para exibir as mensagens mais recentes no topo
                itemCount: messages.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Align(
                    alignment: (index % 2 == 0) ? Alignment.centerLeft : Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: (index % 2 == 0) ? Colors.blueAccent : Colors.greenAccent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        messages[index],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Digite sua mensagem',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                        ),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      sendMessage();
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.send,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void sendMessage() {
    String message = messageController.text;
    if (message.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        messages.insert(0, message); // Adiciona a nova mensagem no topo da lista
      });
      messageController.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Node

```
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const io = new socketio.Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  },
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public')));

let countdownInterval;
let count = 50;
const maxUsersPerRoom = 2;
const roomData = {}; // Contagem de usuários por sala

// função para iniciar o contador
function startCountdown(io, salaId) {
  const room = roomData[salaId];
  console.log("Entrou no contador")
  countdownInterval = setInterval(function () {
    if (room.count >= 0) {
      console.log(`Contador: ${room.count}`)
      io.to(salaId).emit('countdown', room.count); // enviar atualização do contador para todos os clientes na sala
      room.count--;
    } else {
      clearInterval(countdownInterval);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`Nova conexão: ${socket.id}`);

  // Enviar o contador atual para o cliente recém-conectado
  socket.emit('countdown', count);

  socket.on('id_sala', (data) => {
    const salaId = data.salaId;
    const maxUser = data.maxUser; // Obtém o valor de maxUser enviado pelo Flutter
    const idUsuario = data.idUsuario; // Obtém o ID do usuário enviado pelo Flutter

    console.log(`Iniciou: ${salaId}`);
    console.log(`Iniciou: ${maxUser}`);
    console.log(`ID do usuário: ${idUsuario}`);

    // Verificar se a sala existe
    if (!roomData[salaId]) {
      // A sala não existe, criar uma nova sala
      roomData[salaId] = {
        users: [idUsuario],
        count: count,
      };
    } else {
      // A sala existe, adicionar o usuário à sala existente
      roomData[salaId].users.push(idUsuario);
    }

    // Verificar se todos os usuários com o mesmo ID da sala estão conectados
    if (roomData[salaId].users.length === maxUser) {
      // Iniciar o contador para todos os usuários da sala
      console.log(`Iniciou contador`);
      startCountdown(io, salaId);
    }
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(`Disconnected: ${socket.id}`);

    // Remover o usuário das salas ao desconectar
    for (const salaId in roomData) {
      if (roomData.hasOwnProperty(salaId)) {
        const room = roomData[salaId];
        const index = room.users.indexOf(socket.id);
        if (index !== -1) {
          room.users.splice(index, 1);
        }

        // Parar o contador se não houver usuários suficientes na sala
        if (room.users.length < maxUsersPerRoom) {
          clearInterval(countdownInterval);
          delete roomData[salaId];
        }
      }
    }
  });
});

httpServer.listen(3333, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3333');
});
```

it seems that if I use socket.io instead of io.to it loads the counter correctly on the client side.
The problem seems to be in receiving the emit.to